# Why is my code causing a high return value? C++

Tags: c++, performance, return-value

So i made a function that will do a  matrix multiplication and the function seems to do what I want it to do.

However, the program seems to be very slow and when using the function i get a high return value (3221225477).

What is causing this function to run so slow and is there anything I can do to make it faster?

```
friend Matrix operator *(const Matrix &src, const Matrix &src2)  {  
    Matrix TEMP(src.matrixarr.size(),src2.matrixarr[1].size(),0);

    for (int i = 0; i < TEMP.matrixarr.size();i++){
        for (int j= 0; j < TEMP.matrixarr[1].size();i++){
            for( int k = 0; k < src.matrixarr[1].size();i++){
                TEMP.matrixarr[i][j] = src.matrixarr[i][k] + src2.matrixarr[k][j];
            };
        };
    }; 
    return TEMP;
};
```

Comment: is it even actually returning??
it seems an infinite loop to me.

Comment: anyway, could you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? because we can't understand what return value are referring to, this method return a Matrix, not a number.

Comment: You are never incrementing `j` and `k` for starters.

Comment: The high value in hex is 0xC0000005 - which is the error code for ACCESS_VIOLATION on Windows. Could it be just a coincident?

Comment: You could try printing out the values of i, j, and k. Or maybe use a debugger to look at their values. There is a problem with your program and you will see it if you do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 `i++` in your code, which seems not right.

It should be

```
friend Matrix operator *(const Matrix &src, const Matrix &src2)  {  
    Matrix TEMP(src.matrixarr.size(),src2.matrixarr[1].size(),0);

    for (int i = 0; i < TEMP.matrixarr.size();i++){
        for (int j= 0; j < TEMP.matrixarr[1].size();j++){
            for( int k = 0; k < src.matrixarr[1].size();k++){
                TEMP.matrixarr[i][j] = src.matrixarr[i][k] + src2.matrixarr[k][j];
            };
        };
    }; 
    return TEMP;
};
```

---

As for the value `3221225477`, which is `0xC0000005` in hex, it is might because the value `i` is too large and the program can not access the corresponding memory.

Comment: This guy is a newbie at C++, don't give him the straight answer. Give him the tools to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know what is wrong with your program, but it's important that you learn how to debug your program. In this case I'd try to print out values, instead of just using the debugger.

```
friend Matrix operator *(const Matrix &src, const Matrix &src2)  {  
    Matrix TEMP(src.matrixarr.size(),src2.matrixarr[1].size(),0);

    for (int i = 0; i < TEMP.matrixarr.size();i++){
        for (int j= 0; j < TEMP.matrixarr[1].size();i++){
            for( int k = 0; k < src.matrixarr[1].size();i++){
                std::cout << "i:" << i << "j:" << j << "k:" << k << "src.matrixarr[i][k]:" << src.matrixarr[i][k] << "src2.matrixarr[k][j]:" << src2.matrixarr[k][j] << "\n";
                TEMP.matrixarr[i][j] = src.matrixarr[i][k] + src2.matrixarr[k][j];
            };
        };
    }; 
    return TEMP;
};
```

If you do this, you should see something off.

Also, the other answer has problems too, possibly. If you do this my way, you will find out what.